# property accessor creates intersection type instead of union on assignment

Tags: typescript, types

I've faced this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31694

So what's the solution? How do i assign anything to `store[clazz]` without `@ts-ignore` in this example?

```
type Entity_A = { id?: number, prop_a: any }
type Entity_B = { id?: number, prop_b: any }
type EntityStorage = {
    a_entity: Entity_A[]
    b_entity: Entity_B[]
}
type EntityClass = keyof EntityStorage // 'a_entity' | 'b_entity'
type AnyEntityArray = EntityStorage[EntityClass] // Entity_A[] | Entity_B[]
type AnyEntity = NonNullable<EntityStorage[EntityClass]>[number] // Entity_A | Entity_B
 
const a_exampleEntity: Entity_A = { prop_a: null };
const b_exampleEntity: Entity_B = { prop_b: null };
const store: EntityStorage = {
    a_entity: [a_exampleEntity, a_exampleEntity],
    b_entity: [b_exampleEntity, b_exampleEntity],
};
// `as EntityClass` cast is required. In actual code it's value from another EntityStorage instance.
const clazz: EntityClass = 'b_entity' as EntityClass; // 'a_entity' | 'b_entity'
let entities: AnyEntityArray; // Entity_A[] | Entity_B[]
 
// on reading store[clazz] is union
//                                          ↓
// Entity_A[] | Entity_B[]   =   Entity_A[] | Entity_B[]
   entities                  =   store[clazz];
// on writing store[clazz] is union
//            ↓
// Entity_A[] & Entity_B[]   =   Entity_A[] | Entity_B[]
   store[clazz]              =   entities;
/* error says
Entity_A[] | Entity_B[] // union
is not assignable to
Entity_A[] & Entity_B[] // intersection
*/
```

Comment: TS doesn't handle *correlated union types* very well, as described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended approach is to refactor to use generics. In general this requires changes as described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but in this example it should suffice to just make `clazz` generic, say by using an [IIFE](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wXvv9m). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz problem persists in your playground solution if you add type to `entities: AnyEntityArray`

Comment: Right, if you start to undo the refactoring and widen to a union it will not work, for the reasons stated above.  The recommended approach is to make `entities` *generic* and not a union.  If you must annotate it, it should be annotated as `EntityStorage[K]`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOll6N).  Do you understand the situation now?  If so I'll write up an answer (explaining why the problem happens in the first place and why the refactoring to generics works); if not, what mystery remains?

Comment: @jcalz i understand why problem exists. For safe write to ANY entity it creates union type that contains only properties that exist on all entities. I'd say the main point is not to remove `@ts-ignore` but to make clear that `entities` is `typeof store[clazz]`. BUT i have played a little with generics for methods and it did work out. It would be nice if you post full solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is ill-equipped to deal with *correlated union types*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), where you try to write a single block of code that's supposed to work for multiple members of some [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) at the same time.  The improvement for soundness implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) only made this deficiency more apparent, by erring on the side of being safe instead of being unsafe.

If you want to fix this and have the compiler verify the type safety of your code, you'll either need to keep unions and change the single block of code to a block per union member; or refactor to keep the single block of code and change the unions to [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to unions.  This latter approach is the recommended way of dealing with correlated unions, and is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

If you *don't* care about type safety, you can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to push through and move on.  (This is preferable to [the `//@ts-ignore` directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments), which, according to the documentation "only suppresses the error reporting, and we recommend you use [such] comments *very sparingly*".)

---

Let's examine this simplified example of your problem:

```
interface Foo {
  x: { a: 1 };
  y: { b: 2 };
  z: { c: 3 };
}

function union(f: Foo, k: keyof Foo) {
  f[k] = f[k]; // error!
  //~~ <--
  // Type '{ a: 1; } | { b: 2; } | { c: 3; }' is not assignable 
  // to type '{ a: 1; } & { b: 2; } & { c: 3; }'.
}
```

It seems that the line `f[k] = f[k]` should always be correct, but the compiler complains about a union not being an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  The problem here is that the compiler is analyzing `f[k] = f[k]` by comparing the *types* of the expressions instead of the *identity* of the key `k`.  From a type system point of view, the right hand side of the equals sign is *reading* a property from `Foo` at a key `keyof Foo`, and since that's a read position it becomes a union.  The left hand side is *writing* a property to `Foo` at key `keyof Foo`, and since that's a write position it becomes an intersection.  This is completely the right thing to do if all you know is the *types* of the key.  For example, you want this to fail:

```
function unionOops(f: Foo, k1: keyof Foo, k2: keyof Foo) {
  f[k2] = f[k1]; // error!
  //~~~ <--
  // Type '{ a: 1; } | { b: 2; } | { c: 3; }' is not assignable 
  // to type '{ a: 1; } & { b: 2; } & { c: 3; }'.
}
```

Here, `k1` and `k2` are different variables of the same type, and therefore it's possible that you'd be reading and writing incompatible properties.  The only way it would be safe to write into `f[k2]` would be with some value which would work for *every* property of `Foo` (the intersection).

The difference has to do with the *identity* of the keys, and they are not tracked by the compiler.  It can't see the difference between `f[k] = f[k]` and `f[k2] = f[k1]`, and since microsoft/TypeScript#30769 was introduced in TypeScript 3.5 it complains about *both*.  In TypeScript 3.4 and before, both `union()` and `unionOops()` would compile without errors.  Both behaviors are incorrect, but the old behavior was too lax at times while the new behavior is too strict at times.

---

So how can we deal with it in a (mostly) type safe way?  If you want to keep the union types, the only way to do it is to use [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to split the union into cases, and deal with each case separately.  That gives us the redundant thing here:

```
function redundant(f: Foo, k: keyof Foo) {
  switch (k) {
    case "x": f[k] = f[k]; break; // okay
    case "y": f[k] = f[k]; break; // okay
    case "z": f[k] = f[k]; break; // okay
  }
}
```

Nobody wants to do this; it makes more sense if your different cases actually require different code.  But it works.

---

So, if you want a single block of code to be executed once and type check, you'll need to give up on using specific union types, and instead move to *generic* types that are constrained to the union.  Like this:

```
function generic<K extends keyof Foo>(f: Foo, k: K) {
  f[k] = f[k]; // okay
}
```

Here we have an assignment from the generic type `Foo[K]` on the right side, to the generic type `Foo[K]` on the left side.  And the compiler is happy and allows it.  At this point you might wonder: wouldn't the argument about `k1` and `k2` from before imply that this isn't safe? And the answer is.. *yes, this isn't safe*:

```
function genericOops<K extends keyof Foo>(f: Foo, k1: K, k2: K) {
  f[k2] = f[k1]; // okay?!
}
```

But this unsafeness is intentionally supported for generics, as described in [this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559):

> Saying that nothing (other than `any`) is assignable to an indexed access isn't practical, so it becomes a game of *which* unsoundness to permit in order for the feature to be useful. One rule we've always had is that any given type (and, by extension, any `T[K]` for identical `T` and `K`) is by definition assignable to itself, and that's the basic unsoundness we permit.

While this is a hole, it's at least a little easier to patch, because if you have two *possibly unrelated* generic keys `k1` and `k2`, you would probably also have two generic type parameters `K1` and `K2`:

```
function genericOopsFixed<K1 extends keyof Foo, K2 extends keyof Foo>(
  f: Foo, k1: K1, k2: K2
) {
  f[k2] = f[k1]; // error again
}
```

---

Of course, if you just want to keep your original code and move on, you can use a type assertion to tell the compiler to stop bothering you:

```
function assertion(f: Foo, k: keyof Foo) {
  f[k] = f[k] as any; // okay
}
```

It's not type safe at all (or at least the compiler isn't verifying it for you), but it's very expedient.

---

So that's what's going on.  If you want a single block of code to be type checked by the compiler for multiple cases, the multiple cases need to be represented as generics and not unions.

In your example code, since you are not inside a function, you can't just "make it generic".  To do that, you'll need to create a generic function to hold your code block, even if only to call the function immediately like the following [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(<K extends EntityClass>(k: K) => {
  const entities: EntityStorage[K] = store[k];
  store[k] = entities; // okay
})(clazz);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAeAXDsnKQIzIC+A3PsgJ6nbIBGpATLQwQF6tkCUgGZeuGrhgBXEAjDB0IZHKUgAFDFIZ0AGmQBrUoYhN0MNJgCUORjADahgLrIAvMkcu6yAPS-kaCh0KEZ-AD9w5AAeAFpYsICAFSYABxQAcjYKZEofGmQAHzJOZC58orIRZFF8jORgAGdkEHQwckbG4ABzEDh2ABsUROQwLDA0zOyqCoAyEu45qrE6gDpJaTkFdVUQdQB5dFTGrR1MA0NKEzMLK30jLmvzS11bPAIvLlcPL0pnBikm3kimUyCgEAAJnIIXBwKc7hcnrdXnYCI0AO7AMAIAAWyA0hjejAICDgjRQACJCBTSF5vp4nP8OOC4IY+ARhGTKUwaQyXO4+Uz2Cy2cTOeTkBT+Ly6QK6T5hRBWeypIDcEDtqDuhAQNBgAhogBpQKESAgCHNUzPO4APnhukRyENRI+jLljJ8-mQ6EMcCYG1kwJ22t1UH1h2ORpNZotRhuL0wdu0CKMVydF0eTpdfK+7suTK9Pr9AH4AIQbDUglQhvUICONVDAQiQo3UCCmnWxq3I85OnjtmOW+O2jT2M73S6kQ2UDNTri4bOfem-AsBIIhcjdOCgCuBzUqMnkqBV+294xx60o96CvOuMnkEBMT0BIv+wETdLIACi4CxTAA+gAggKbDABCxakCAMgALbsNABipMEqT-jksJMLQuAfigP6KBM-4AEIgQ04GQTBcFQAhSH-qUaEYVh36-hMADKYxQHA2ogYwcD-jquEsAxfFAQ4ziMOwPGMfxOF-gRwkbPRUkTAAwgMh4Ct2lgKUwLEhOxKBehk3G8X+9TFBkYlGRMGSYZMyCAY+mmAVAbHoR4mnaWx2oOJpymHq4XqaUJrjFAF+GyfRdlMJpAoAHLKNFMgDCpgwQNEbmsbpXkST5nTODaDhQbB0B+QEAXAcFEkEeqCDKI07SGYQcDQakQyaaQpVEYhRwoaRiUSNVIC1RwPENU1LUSW1FWER4bCdchpRQb19C4P1g21SEEATXx7m6ZxBCGeNyAOPVjXNRAmkGMdo1nRJzh6KJ4l8aQDjmSNp3nUN7YnWNfG3ZIDDLTV7QICp-CCAJf7Zc0HhmQ9xkdODSkqZ0z7IAZsOWZUMMWUwVlDO0FnABAjSkBFDlOX6KOlcJlQhbJuAaFGA6ds03lI40drns67g2qiwiA4EjGE8TCNaelnmGvSa3gh6jBSxAboeATRMo6+kjWBowNwKD1gMEAA)